# Understanding python's behavior towards lists and list indices

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
names = ['a', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'b']

stuff = [['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['b', 5], ['c', 4], ['c', 2], ['d', 10], ['e', 22], ['e', 13]]

x = [[0] * len(stuff)] * len(names)

counters = [0]*len(names)

for s in stuff:
    i = names.index(s[0])
    x[i][counters[i]] = s
    counters[i] += 1

for i in range(len(names)):
    if 0 in x[i]:
        x[i] = x[i][:x[i].index(0)]

print x
```

What I would like to have is the following output:

```
[[['a', 1], ['a', 2]], [['e', 22], ['e', 13]], [['c', 4], ['c', 2]], [['d', 10]], [['b', 5]]]
```

Essentially, I want to create a new list that contains sublists of sublists where the 0th entry of the sublists at the lowest level is always the same (sorry, I don't know how to put it in a better way). I want to create this new list from the sublists in 'stuff' by using the elements of 'names'. What I get when running my code is:

```
[[['e', 22], ['e', 13]], [['e', 22], ['e', 13]], [['e', 22], ['e', 13]], [['e', 22], ['e', 13]], [['e', 22], ['e', 13]]]
```

My question is: why does my code produce this output instead of what i want? I am pretty sure that things go wrong in the line

```
x[i][counters[i]] = s
```

However, I have no idea why so any help would really be appreciated...